# Finding derivative of this integral function.

Tags: random

I need help on finding the derivative of this:

$$g(x) = \int_1^{x^2} (x-t)\sin^2(t)dt$$

I thought about taking out x and having it as a constant but how?

Comment: Don't delete it. Post your answer as an answer for others to see.

Comment: And return the question.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute the parentheses into two integrals and differentiate from there using the fundamental theorem.

$$g'(x) = \int_1^{x^2} \sin^2(t)dt + 2x^2\sin^2(x^2)-2x^3\sin^2(x^2)=\\
(-2 + 2 x^2 + \sin 2 - \sin(2 x^2))/4 + 2x^2\sin^2(x^2)-2x^3\sin^2(x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

From Fundamental theorem of calculus, we have:

$$g(x) = x\int_1^{x^2}\sin^2(t)dt-\int_1^{x^2} t\sin^2(t)dt=x[F(x^2)-F(1)]-[H(x^2)-H(1)]$$

where

$$F(x^2)=\int_1^{x^2}\sin^2(t)dt,\ \ \  H(x^2)=\int_1^{x^2}t\sin^2(t)dt$$

and from Product rule:

$$g'(x) =F(x^2)-F(1)+ 2x^2 F'(x^2)-2x H'(x^2)$$

To calculate it, you have to solve the integral

$$F(x^2)=\int_1^{x^2}\sin^2(t)dt$$